# Пробема с получением счетчика расшариваний ссылки на Faceebook

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Возникла проблема при получении счетчика кол-ва расшариваний страницы, проблема хитрая, очень хитрая, итак: для теста в браузере вбиваю - https://graph.facebook.com/?id={url}&fields=id,share&access_token={app_id}|{app_secret}

Использую access_token в данном случае потому, что запрос будет выполняться с сервера на сервер и чтобы не заморачиваться с получением data-access-token передаю непосредственно пару "{ID приложения}|{секретный ключ приложения}";
{url} - доступен из веба и отладчик фейсбука показывает "Отметки «Нравится», перепосты и комментарии: **1** More Info".

Итого, в браузере получаею результат в виде json:

```
{
   "id": "{переданный мной URL}",
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 1
   }
}
```

Все прекрасно!

Проблема: если я ту же ссылку запрашиваю курлом (метод GET) - получаю ответ:

```
{
   "id": "{переданный мной URL}",
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 0
   }
}
```

То есть - при переходе по ссылке в браузере share_count содержит верное значение - 1, но при запросе того же URLа курлом - share_count содержит 0!

Пробовал передавать курлом USER_AGENT своего браузера, но это предположение "не очень" ибо если бы фейсбук проверял кто пытается запросить данные и USER_AGENT или в целом клиент был бы важен - он бы просто не отдавал данные вовсе, а не менял их..

ВАЖНО: пришла мысль, что я делаю запрос из браузера, в котором у меня сохранена авторизация того пользователя фейсбука, под которым было создано приложение.. Проверил эту теорию, попробовал из другого браузера без авторизации на фейсбуке, попробовал в режиме инкогнито - результат тот же - из браузера в share_count верное число, при запросе с сервера курлом - 0!

Помогите, подскажите пожалуйста в чем тут дело! Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, укажите _точную_ ссылку, которую открываете в браузере и команду curl, выполняемую на сервере. Пока что ставлю на то, что URL в запросах отличаются.

Comment: Роман, спасибо за ответ. Проверял это в первую очередь, но нет - урл одинаковый. Сейчас проверил тот же самый код на бекенде по которому делал описание в этом вопросе - share_count теперь верный - 1. Объяснить это с точки зрения своих действий не могу ибо ничего не менял со своей стороны, видимо, как-то избирательно работает некий кеш на фейсбуке, больше версий у меня нет...

Comment: Судя по заголовкам, дело не в HTTP-кэшировнании. Так что, действительно, выглядит, как какая-то внутренняя фейсбучная история.